# how to join these clauses together: "No more in your class" and "I will always be your student"

Tags: meaning-in-context, clauses

I am a student, but sometimes a bit naughty by asking too many silly questions, and my teachers have to stay with me after classes are over.
On FxxeBook, I found some people say these to their teachers:
"No more in your class" and "I will always be your student"
I tried to join the two sentences toegther:
"Even if I am no more in your class, but I will always be your student" 
Does this sound good to teachers?

Comment: In the real world these days, no. The young will eventually know more than the original teacher, and they could even become a teacher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"No more in your class" sounds like a Twitterism -- an archaic or slightly awkward usage that has fewer letters, so it's more likely to fit into a "tweet" on Twitter. Or maybe it's a poetical meme that's going around that I don't know about, since I'm not on FB.

To join the concepts, I'd say, "Though I'm no longer in your class, I will always be your student."

Comment: Hi A.Beth. Does it make sense if someone says "I will always be your student" to his teacher? Why do people use future tense to express a feeling or something that is currently happening. I am looking for some similar questions on ELL.

Comment: It's kind of a sidelong way of saying, "I will always respect you," basically, by invoking the teacher/student relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Although A.Beth has already posted a very good answer I'd like to add the following.

"*Why do people use future tense to express a feeling or something that is currently happening*"

> "I will always love you!" or "I will never do drugs.".

It's meant to be like a promise to go on with something/feeling/attitude/habit... (forever).
You could also say:

> "I am your student *now* and I will be your student *in the future*."

The fact that the teacher seems to be very good and honestly appreciated, makes a person realize that (s)he will always be *the teacher's student*, no matter what will happen. Therefore the student is already sure what his feelings in the future will be like.